# How can handle a FileTransfer plugin request in ASP .NET WEB API

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile application about sound files (like .3gp, .wav), and I want send user's record to .net web api server. For this situation I used Ionic Native FileTransfer plugin.

```
console.log(this.postModel.sound.substr(this.postModel.sound.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));

let fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

let options: FileUploadOptions = {
  fileKey: 'file',
  fileName: this.postModel.sound.substr(this.postModel.sound.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
  mimeType: 'audio/3gp',
  httpMethod: 'post',
  chunkedMode: false,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": btoa("user" + ":" + "password"),
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  }
}

var params = {};

params['userID'] = this.postModel.userID;
params['dateTime'] = this.postModel.dateTime;

options.params = params;  //this.postModel.sound is path of files

fileTransfer.upload(this.postModel.sound, this.apiUrl + '/posts/record', options, true)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('Posted!')
  }, (err) => {
    console.log('ERROR!' + err.value)
  });
```

So, this function's request can catch by web api

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Http.Route("record")]
public IHttpActionResult PostRecord(){
   var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
   ....
}
```

But, I can't see anything from Ionic's request in Current.Request.

How can fix it?